# Como Guardar imagenes en un volumen en fly.io con una aplicacion web en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo desplegada una aplicación web en fly.io de Laravel y todo me funciona bien localmente porque guardo mis imagenes en mi carpeta public, pero al momento de desplegarlo en fly.io se debe de vincular con un volumen que se crea pero no me da error los pasos que indica el docs de fly.io, quisiera saber si alguien puede resolver mi duda y problema.